# Change a variable in main from a function

Tags: c++, scope, global-variables

I'm looking for functionality similar to the python `global` keyword.  I want to change a variable declared in main from a function.

For example:

```
void f() {
    x = 5;
}

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    f();
    cout << x; // prints 5

}
```

Any solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list Learn the language before asking about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a reference passed to the function

```
void f(int& x) {
    x = 5;
}

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    f(x);
    cout << x; // prints 5
}
```

or a global variable (discouraged!)

```
int x = 0;

void f() {
    x = 5;
}

int main() {
    x = 0;
    f();
    cout << x; // prints 5
}
```

Comment: How would I format this if I'm passing an array by reference?

Comment: @CSGregorian What do you mean _"How would I format this if I'm passing an array by reference?"_? How to print a `std::array<int,N>` or `std::vector<int>` to `std::cout`?!? That's a completely different question, as what you've been asking for here!

Comment: No, no, sorry, forget the cout, that was just an example.  If I wanted to pass an array, it would be `void f(int (&x)[])`, right?

Comment: @CSGregorian You can't use references for c-style array types well, stick to `std::array<int,N>` or `std::vector<int>` to deal with reference parameters. Also you should clarify your question about this point. As it is, it has nothing to do with what you're actually asked in your comment here!